# How to get value of a hidden element? (Watir)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

just wondering, how can I get the value of a hidden element using watir? This is the element:

```
<input type="hidden" value="randomstringhere" id="elementid" name="elementname" />
```

And this is my code atm:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
$browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
$browser.goto("http://www.site.com")
$grabelement = $browser.hiddens(:id, "elementid")
$blah = $grabelement.attribute_value("value")
puts $blah
```

This gets stuck at the last line, where it returns

```
code.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method `attribute_value' for #<Watir::HiddenCollection:0x8818adc> (NoMethodError)
```

Sorry for the basic question, I've had a search and couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's with all the global variables? That's a bad sign in a Ruby script.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I'm just putting those for the moment, as a reminder to make me check all of them - I'm currently writing all the methods separately, and I'm gonna go through and fix them all :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem**

Your code is quite close. The problem is the line:

```
$grabelement = $browser.hiddens(:id, "elementid")
```

This line says to get a collection (ie all) of hidden elements that have id "elementid". As the error message says, the collection does not have the attribute_value method. Only elements (ie the objects in the collection) have the method.

**Solution (assuming single hidden with matching id)**

Assuming that there is only one, you should just get the first match using the `hidden` instead of `hiddens` (ie drop the `s`):

```
$grabelement = $browser.hidden(:id, "elementid")
$blah = $grabelement.value
puts $blah
#=> "randomstringhere"
```

Note that for the value attribute, you can just do `.value` instead of `.attribute_value('value')`.

**Solution (if there are multiple hiddens with matching id)**

If there actually are multiple, then you can iterate over the collection or just get the first, etc:

```
#Iterate over each hidden that matches
browser.hiddens(:id, "elementid").each{ |hidden| puts hidden.value }

#Get just the first hidden in the collection
browser.hiddens(:id, "elementid").first.value
```

Comment: How do I click a hidden element ? I get the exception - `fxdriver.preconditions.visible': Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError) . I have checked this is the only element by with that id.

Comment: @stack1, why do you want to click a hidden element? Watir is meant to mimic user actions. Since a user cannot click a hidden element, Watir does not allow it.

Comment: @JustinKo - Graphically speaking, that element is text (which a human can click) which lets you remove criteria from a search page. Humans can click this but, watir cannot ? Is there a way around this ? Thanks.

Comment: @stack1, I think we are using different terminology. The hidden element in this question is referring to `<input type="hidden">` elements. To my knowledge, no browser displays this input type. So if a human can see/click it, it is likely something else. You should create a new question so that we can see how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JustinKo - Ok. Thanks. Will do. I saw input type = hidden there though.